# How to change validation message in openapi in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have spring boot application that constructs dtos based on openapi yaml configuration. I want to change default messages of validation errors. Now they are in russian but I want them to be in english. How can I do that?
Example of message:
cart.items[0].feedId не должно равняться null
I need this to be:
cart.items[0].feedId must not be null
For all validation errors

Answer (score 0):

In SpringWebflux you should just change the Locale.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
  SpringApplication.run(YandexMarketAdapterApplication.class, args);
```

}